# How to add WPF page to tabcontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this main wpf window
[image: Main WPF window]

and this WPF page

[image: WPF page]

I need to add this page to tabcontrol in main window

This is my OnRender method

```
   protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        if (ISFirstRender)
        {
            TabItem tabitem = new TabItem();
            tabitem.Header = "Tab 3";
            pan1.Items.Add(tabitem);
            Page1 page1 = new Page1();
            tabitem.Content = new Page1();

            ISFirstRender = false;
        }

        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }
```

after the application running I faced this exception while selecting the new tab 
[image: Main WPf window after add tab3]

[image: Error after select tab 3]

I need to know how to add wpf page to existing tabcontroll

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to add a new `Page`, as opposed to a `UserControl`, you can create a new `Frame` object and place the page in there.

```
    if (ISFirstRender)
    {
        TabItem tabitem = new TabItem();
        tabitem.Header = "Tab 3";
        Frame tabFrame = new Frame();
        Page1 page1 = new Page1();
        tabFrame.Content = page1;
        tabitem.Content = tabFrame;
        pan1.Items.Add(tabitem);

        ISFirstRender = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add user controls to the `TabControl`. So go to the add new items and select the user control and make what you want (like what you have in the page). Then add an instance of that user control to the `TabControl`.

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    if (ISFirstRender)
    {
        TabItem tabitem = new TabItem();
        tabitem.Header = "Tab 3";
        pan1.Items.Add(tabitem);

        MyUserControl userControl = new MyUserControl();
        tabitem.Content = userControl;

        ISFirstRender = false;
    }

    base.OnRender(drawingContext);
}
```