# Open new page in WPF using vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How can you open a new page in WPF? I know when I'm using WinForms you can use

```
dim myPage as new myPage
MyPage.show
```

But how can I do this in WPF?

And how can I do this
[How to add WPF page to tabcontrol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589298/how-to-add-wpf-page-to-tabcontrol#)
, but in Visual Basic?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, what did you try

Comment: Hi, And thanks. I wanted to load my page into a tabcontrol.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question :

```
// Create a window from the page you need to show
   MyPage window = new MyPage();

// Open a your page
   window.Show();
```

Comment: But how do you write this in vb ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the VB equivalent of @moez code.

```
' Create a window from the page you need to show
   Dim window As New MyPage()

' Open your page
   window.Show()
```

Comment: Show is not a member of wpfapplication.mypage i use mypage.xaml

Answer (score -1):

An exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code